# Existence of some sort of 'infinite algebraicity' of transcendental numbers

Tags: number-theory, analysis, complex-analysis

Given an arbitrary number, say, $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, can anyone supply either

(a) a reason for the existence (or general non-existence) of, or

(b) the reverse engineering of

a (convergent) power series $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ with rational coefficients for which $f(\alpha) = 0$? (This problem is trivial when the number in question is algebraic, so feel free to assume transcendentality.) I'm looking for a push in the right direction; any input is welcome.

--

prototypical example: $\alpha = \pi$ with $f(z) = \sum \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} z^{2n+1}$ = sin z

--

I imagine that this question could easily be recast in several different directions. Please add any appropriate tags if you suspect this too.

Comment: My money (um....except that there isn't anyone taking bets AFAIK) is on existence.

Comment: Are you asking that for every complex number $\alpha$, there exists a convergent series with rational coefficients such that it computes to $\alpha$? Do you want it to be absolutely convergent?

Comment: This is an interesting question! Small quibble- shouldn't your power series for sin have z^{2n+1}, rather than z^n?

Comment: @Patrick: I'm not sure what you're asking in your first question. As for your second, absolute convergence would be nice, but at the moment I'd settle for anything weaker.

Comment: @NKS: yes, of course. It's fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: not answering anything, but found while looking and interesting to me at least, http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1946-52-12/S0002-9904-1946-08707-8/S0002-9904-1946-08707-8.pdf constructs rational power series st $f(a)$ is transcendental for all algebraic $a\neq0$ in the radius of convergence.

Comment: The [Weierstrauss Product Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassProductTheorem.html) seems relevant...

Comment: @Matt: given some Weierstrass product which has a linear term involving $\alpha$, how can we be sure that, after distributing everything out into a power series, we'd be left with something with rational coefficients?

Comment: I think you want to exclude the trivial solution all $a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact you can do better. Suppose  $\alpha_n$ is a sequence of distinct nonzero complex numbers with $|\alpha_n| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, and $\beta_n$ is any sequence of complex numbers.  Of course a power series with real coefficients satisfies
$f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$, so I'll require that if $\alpha_n = \overline{\alpha_m}$ then $\beta_n = \overline{\beta_m}$.  Then there is an entire function $f(z)$, given by a power series $f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j z^j$ with all $c_j$ rational, such that $f(\alpha_n) = \beta_n$ for all $n$.

Note that by a consequence of Weierstrass's and Mittag-Lefler's theorems, for any such sequence $\alpha_n$ and any $N$, there is an entire function taking prescribed values at all $\alpha_n$ and also prescribed values for the first $N$ coefficients of its Maclaurin series.

Start with an entire function (guaranteed by the cited theorem) $f_0$ such that $f_0(\alpha_n) = \beta_n$ and 
$f_0(\overline{\alpha_n}) = \overline{\beta_n}$ for all $n$.  Since $(f_0(z) + \overline{f_0(\overline{z}})/2$ satisfies the same conditions, we may assume $f_0(\overline{z}) = \overline{f_0(z)}$.
Suppose $f_n$ is such a function where in addition the coefficients of $c_0, \ldots, c_{n-1}$ of its Maclaurin series are rational.
Consider $f_{n+1}(z) = f_n(z) + t g_n(z)$ where all $g_n(\alpha_k) = 0$, 
$g_n(\overline{z}) = \overline{g_n(z)}$, and the Maclaurin series of $g_n$ starts
with $z^n$.  There is a dense set of $t \in \mathbb R$ for which the coefficient of $z^n$ in $f_{n+1}(z)$ will be rational.  I will choose such a $t$ small enough that
$|t| \max \{|g_n(z)|: |z| \le n\} < 1/n^2$.  Then the sequence $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on compact sets to an entire function $f$, which has the required properties.

Comment: Fantastic! Originally, what I had in mind was finding an entire function with rational coefficients that vanished at the given number, but I thought that it might have been too strong/specific a question to start off with (and that it might scare away questions and comments). Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This is straightforward for arbitrary real $r$. First, let $a_0 = 1$ WLOG. Choose $a_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that $|a_0 + a_1 r| < \frac{1}{2}$ (a sufficiently good rational approximation to $- \frac{a_0}{r}$ suffices). For any $n$, if $a_0, ... a_{n-1}$ have been chosen, it is always possible to choose in a similar fashion $a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ so that
$$\left| a_0 + a_1 r + ... + a_n r^n \right| < \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

The conclusion follows. Of course you can replace $\frac{1}{2^n}$ by a sequence decaying arbitrarily quickly to $0$.

For complex $r$ it's trickier; note that for purely imaginary $r$ the first step already fails. If some integer power of $r$ is real then we can proceed as above; otherwise, the argument is messier. We should consider an increasing sequence $t_n$ of positive integers such that $r^{t_n}$ has very small imaginary part relative to its real part (but not too small or else we won't be able to cancel out the imaginary part of the previous terms) and only tweak the corresponding terms $a_{t_n}$. The desired result is true in this case but the details are a bit annoying (the key observation is that the sequence $\frac{r^n}{|r|^n}$ is dense in the unit circle).

Comment: Thank you for the response. May you please elaborate on the complex case?

Comment: @JSeaton: using the last observation in the post, we can find $t_1$ so that $r^{t_1}$ has imaginary part, say, at most $\frac{1}{10}$ of its real part. Then the first step still works. Next we find $t_2$ so that $r^{t_2}$ has approximately the negative of the same ratio of real to imaginary part, so the second step will still work. Graphically the idea is to find vectors $\frac{r^{t_n}}{|r|^{t_n}}$ which can be used to move to $0$ from $1$ on the complex plane in a reasonably efficient manner. There are a lot of choices in this construction and it's a bit annoying to actually make them.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your construction does not give absolute convergence. Do you think there is some easy fix for this?